# CKEditor 4.3.3 split base64 string to store on different attribute

Tags: java, ckeditor, base64

I am using CKEditor 4.3.3 in my current application mapped to text area field in jsp and entire RTF content are store as attribute value in database.

Due to value limit on attribute I am not able to store large RTF content (Ex. if I put snapshot and ckeditor convert RTF content to base64 string and that base64 content I am storing on attribute since this base64 string in huge which is not possible to store on one single attribute)

So I want to store this base64 string on 3 different attribute by doing compression.

attrType > HTML

attrText > only text from RTF field (exluding img snapshot etc)

attrData > entire RTF base64 string

Question -

1. Is there any way / API that i can use to split current base64 string to store it on 3 different attribute ?
2. What compression/decompression mechanism I should use for this ?

Comment: Do you mean in Java, or in Javascript? These are 2 very different languages.

Comment: I want to do it in Java.

Comment: Input -

'<s>scratch text</s><br><a href="http://www.google.com" data-cke-saved-href="http://www.google.com">link text</a><br><span class="marker">style text</span><h1>format text</h1><ol><li>Number<br></li><li>Number Two<br></li></ol><ul><li>Bullet1<br></li><li>Bullet2<br></li></ul><br><img data-cke-saved-src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORwggg==" alt=""><br><br><br>'

Comment: Output - 

'attrType =
HTML

attrText =
scratch text
link text
style text (span class marker)
1. Number
2. Number Two
• Bullet1
• Bullet2
<image-sanpshot> 

attrData = entire RTF base64 input string'